# Linear independence of sinusoidal functions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

It is very obvious that $\sin(x), \cos(x), \sin(2x), \cos(2x), \sin(3x)...$ are linearly independent functions since:

$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)+c\sin(2x)+d\cos(2x)+...=0$ requires that $a,b,c,...=0$

However, is it true that all $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ are linearly independent when $k$ is not an integer?

Comment: Why is it obvious that they are linearly independent when the $k$'s are integers but not otherwise?

Comment: If k's are integers, then I can multiply by sin(nx) and the integrate from -pi to +pi.  The only non vanishing term will be the coefficient of sin(nx).  Thus, doing it one by one, I can show that all the coefficients are zero.  However, how do I show that all sine and cosine functions are linearly independent if I include non-integral number of k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have functions of the type $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$, with several values of $k>0$. In order to prove that they are linearly independent, you can use the fact that their second derivative is $-k^2$ times themselves. So, using the fact that eigenvectors which correspond to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent, the only possibility that remains is that $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ are linearly dependent, but they are not, since they are not multiple of each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'm wondering further that does it work if I include k=0 as well (i.e. a + b + csin(x) + dcos(x) + esin(2x) + ... = 0)

Comment: @delickcrow123 Of course not, since $\sin(0\times x)=0$.

Comment: May I ask can I show that a + csin(x) + dcos(x) + esin(2x) + ... = 0 then a=0? (ignoring the sine term)

Comment: @delickcrow123 By the same argument that I used before: $1$ is an eigenvector (with eigenvalues $0$) of the linear map $f\mapsto f''$.